# Silencing Flyway -- a log4j problem

Tags: java, logging, log4j, flyway

I've written a wrapper around [Flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/) I call [Nomad](http://github.com/blt/Nomad). I am well pleased with Flyway, save the incessant logging it performs outside of Maven. I created an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=133&sort=reporter&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Reporter%20Summary%20Stars). Each user of Nomad must make their own configuration of log4j to silence Flyway. This is problematic if not done, for instance, during Spec testing. However, getting the configuration *just right* is a challenge and, moreover, having to do this breaks the abstraction of my library.

My question is this: how can I permanently silence flyway so that any user of Nomad is not burdened with the task? I've found that this `log4j.xml` *sometimes* works:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %t %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <level value="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This stifles Flyway to the point of being helpful, rather than overly chatty. The misdirection is still broken, but not often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have done it in `log4j.xml` seems good. I don't see anything wrong.

Since the project uses Maven, I recommend you adding a property file instead `log4j.properties`, that you place that in `src/main/resources`

The contents can be:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stderr
log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %c %x: %m%n

# Silence springframework messages.
org.springframework=ERROR
```

Perhaps that will work better with you. It becomes easier to manage too.

Comment: I am not clear on the purpose of your recommendation. Nomad uses SBT--Apache Ivy underneath--and while Flyway _does_ use Maven as its build tool by the time I get to the use of it Flyway is simply a jar. Also, thank you for the more terse properties equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Flyway's only non-logging framework dependency is Spring. As Mohamed Mansour pointed out you can **suppress all but the ERROR messages** with a simple Log4J configuration setting.

For Spring (as pointed out by Mohamed Mansour):

```
org.springframework=ERROR
```

For Flyway:

```
com.googlecode.flyway=ERROR
```

Comment: This then becomes a necessary configuration step for every Nomad user; I would much prefer that this be done _once_ in Nomad.